# Non Zero excess status when installing RQuantLib

Tags: r, macos, quantlib

I am trying to install RQuantLib on a Mac OSX 10.13. I have the latest version of R: Version 3.4.3.

I have done the following pre requisites using homebrew

```
brew install boost
brew install quantlib
```

However, when I try

```
install.packages("RQuantLib", configure.args="--with-boost include=/usr/local/include/ --with-boost-lib=/usr/local/lib/")
```

R returns

```
* installing *source* package ‘RQuantLib’ ...
** package ‘RQuantLib’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for g++... g++
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for R... yes
checking for quantlib-config... yes
checking for Boost development files... yes
checking for minimal Boost version... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
Completed configuration and ready to build.
** libs
clang++  -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG          
-I"/Users/rorymcstay/Library/R/3.4/library/Rcpp/include" -    
I/usr/local/include  -Wall -g -O2  -
I/usr/local/Cellar/quantlib/1.12/include  -I/usr/local/include/ -
I../inst/include -I. -fopenmp -DRCPP_NEW_DATE_DATETIME_VECTORS -fPIC  -
Wall -g -O2  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
make: *** [RcppExports.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RQuantLib’
* removing ‘/Users/rorymcstay/Library/R/3.4/library/RQuantLib’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘RQuantLib’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
‘/private/var/folders/mf/7p4rjjq53zg5_3bdqznb9p2h0000gn/T/RtmpsowkET/do    wnloaded_packages’
```

Can anyone see what is going wrong?

Thanks

Rory

Comment: the error would appear to be this line `clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'`. I believe that the version of clang on Mac doesn't support openmp -- although maybe that has since changed in which case you could update xcode. I would try googling that error message and see if you can find a workaround.

Comment: I tried that before approaching the stack exchange. I will edit my question to summarise what I tried. Thank you